# Tabulator table specific styling

Tags: html, css, tabulator, custom-formatting

I have 3 tabulator tables in a single HTML page. I want to add a custom class with a specific styling or add a custom styling. E.g.

```css
overflow-x: hidden
```

to one table and not affecting others. How can I do that without changing any default styling of other tables on the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above examples are correct, you just need to apply the ID or class to the div holding the table instead so it would be:

HTML

```
<div id="table-1"></div>
```

JS

```
var table = new Tabulator("#table-1",{...});
```

CSS

```
#table-1{
    ///your styles here
}
```

Though i would be wary about changing properties like overflow on the table element, they will likely result in unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can give that table an `id` and apply the style to the `id`. You can do something like:

**style.css**

```
#custom_table{
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<table id="custom_table"></table>
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I already know this.But I'm using tabulator plugin http://tabulator.info/

Answer (score 0):

just add unique class to table tag in which you want to apply style.

```
<table class="custom-table">
   <table>
      <table>
      </table>
   </table>
</table>
```

css

```
.custom-table {
   overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I already know this.But I'm using tabulator plugin [http://tabulator.info/]

Comment: Okay, Then you can add custom class using **cssClass** option